# meaning of 'have' in "have me saying ~"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from [the transcript of a podcast](https://freakonomics.com/podcast/did-michael-lewis-just-get-lucky-with-moneyball/).

> He was so angry. And I said “Billy, wait, what, like, what’s the
> problem here?” And he said, “It’s me, the way, you’re describing me.”
> I said, “How did I describe you? How does it bother you?” And he says,
> “You **have** me saying ‘f***’ all the time.” And I said, “You do say
> ‘f***’ all the time.”

I'm curious what the meaning of "have" is in the above context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, *to have someone do something* = *to **cause / force** them to do it*.

But in OP's context it's more like ***describe / depict** someone as doing / being like something*. This is very much an *idiomatic* usage that learners should be cautious about adopting (it can occur in formal as well as informal contexts, but it's never *necessary*, and it's easily misused).

---

I think the *reason* this usage is "easily misused" is connected to the fact that it's effectively *derived* from the more common ***cause / force*** sense.

Consequently, the ***depict*** sense carries overtones of the "subject" *being in control* (he *chooses* to depict the "object" in a certain way, *forcing* his description to apply). This can sometimes imply criticism of the subject (for choosing to apply a description that the *current* writer / speaker ***doesn't agree with***).

You can see that implication in OP's actual example, where Billy clearly doesn't agree with the way he's been depicted!

Answer (score 2):

Billy says that Lewis describes or represents Billy as swearing all the time (in Lewis' book).

> To represent as doing something. U.S. colloq.
>
> Oxford English Dictionary 2nd Edition

Comment: I don't buy that **U.S. colloq.** bit. It's "normal" English for ***all*** Anglophones, and the results from a Google Books search for the sequence [***gospel has Jesus***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gospel+has+jesus%22) returns at least *hundreds* of relevant instances - from what certainly don't look like "colloquial" source texts to me.